# Wait Process Window to be Activate

Tags: powershell

I'm using a PowerShell script:

```
Start-Process c:\test\window.exe
```

I'm trying to make it wait until `window.exe` becomes activate (window process appears in the screen) to continue the script. I have a 60s "timeout", but there is a chance that the process exceeds 60s.

```
$NumOfSecs = 60;
$n = $NumOfSecs;
Write-Host "Starting in " -NoNewLine;
do {
    if ($n -lt $NumOfSecs) {
        Write-Host ", " -NoNewLine
    };
    Write-Host $n -NoNewLine;
    $n = $n - 1;
    Start-Sleep 1
} while ($n -gt 0)
```

Comment: you may be able to run a do loop that checks for the process to appear in the process list. then perhaps you could test the window title ... i have not tested it, but it _seems_ that the window title for a firefox window only fills in when the window is "ready".